# Magento 2 Add custom font to Email Template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am adding custom fonts to Luma theme and followed this tutorial:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

i have added fonts to :

> {luma-theme-path}/web/fonts

_typography.less file :

> .lib-font-face(
>        @family-name:@font-family-name__base,
>        @font-path: '@{baseDir}/fonts/my_font_name',
>        @font-weight: 400,
>        @font-style: normal
>    );

updated _variables.less file for fonts as below:

> //  Fonts
>   @font-family-name__base: 'my_family_name';
>   @font-family__base: @font-family-name__base;

I used my_family_name in Email templates css. But this font does not apply to email.

I have also executed following commands:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Have you found any solution ?